# 401 while trying to access Swagger UI - Springdoc

Tags: spring, springdoc

I was writing spring application.I added swagger into my project but somehow It couldn't run properly.Into my project also has bearer authentication with token. Please give me a hint How I might fix this problem

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.44</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: It says HTTP 401 unauthorized. The problem's going to be in how your security is set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is in your security setting. All resources/endpoints are protected by default when security is present on class path. What you need to do is to expose all resource that are needed for Swagger UI publicly. To do so you have at least two options. The first is to change or create configuration like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("swagger-ui/**", "swagger-ui**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/v3/api-docs**");
    }
```

By this you override whole HttpSecurity for mentioned paths means no CORS, CSRF, authorization will be checked.

**The other option is to try** [Havelock](https://github.com/Majlanky/havelock). With the library you can expose swagger resource by one annotation.
Disclaimer: I am the founder and tech lead of the project

Answer (score 0):

First of all use the last stable version.

This should help:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.4</version>
   </dependency>
```

If the issue still persists, add more relevant information about your code to reproduce it.